# SOQL: Return Most Recent Attachment w/ Body

Tags: soql, lookup, query, attachment

I have a data model where I have an Object, Software_License__c, which contains a Lookup to an Account. There are Attachments against the Software License. I can safely assume the Software License has one attachment, but a given Account may have multiple Software Licenses. The Software License contains a DateTime called Date__c.

I need to return the Attachment (with Body) of the most recent Software License given the ID of the Account lookup.

I've tried a few things.

```
SELECT  Id , Date__c, (SELECT   Id, Body ,Name FROM Attachments LIMIT 1)
FROM    Software_License__c
WHERE   Account__c = :CurrentUser.AccountId
ORDER BY Date__c DESC
```

This does not work because you can't return binary data (e.g., the attachment body) from a subquery.

```
select  Id, Body, Name  from    Attachment 
where   ParentId in (select Id  from Software_License__c where Account__c = :CurrentUser.AccountId ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

that doesn't work because you need to select `Date__c` to ORDER BY it.

I can't think of a way to make this work with just one query. Anyone have a thought? TIA.

Comment: I've always done this with 2 queries

Comment: Why order by for an inner join?

Comment: In the end we did make two loops. While it's a little jarring to see a nested query, in the outer loop we had a LIMIT 1, which means it's no more than two queries. Less desirable than just one, but gets the job done.

Outer Loop:
`for(Software_License__c sl : [select Id from Software_License__c where Account__c = :CurrentUser.AccountId order by Date__c desc limit 1])`

Inner Loop:
`for(Attachment att : [select Id, Body, Name from Attachment where ParentId = :sl.Id limit 1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Restating as answer my above comment)

In the end we did make two loops. While it's a little jarring to see a nested query, in the outer loop we had a LIMIT 1, which means it's no more than two queries. Less desirable than just one, but gets the job done.

```
for(Software_License__c sl : [select Id from Software_License__c where Account__c = :CurrentUser.AccountId order by Date__c desc limit 1]) 
{
    for(Attachment att : [select Id, Body, Name from Attachment where ParentId = :sl.Id limit 1]) 
    {
    }
}
```

Kudos to my developer colleagues for the assist on this one.

Comment: That's still a query in a `for` loop, which seems highly inadvisable.

Comment: The outer loop is LIMIT 1 which guarantees it only runs once. I agree the aesthetics of it are terrible but in the end it's guaranteed to be just two queries.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Id as a ORDER BY parameter rather than the date. Try this (untested, btw):

```
SELECT  Id, Body, Name  
FROM    Attachment 
WHERE   ParentId IN (SELECT Id  
                     FROM Software_License__c 
                     WHERE Account__c = :CurrentUser.AccountId 
                     ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

This is assuming that date roughly corresponds to created date, of course.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't make that assumption. But I like your idea that Id's are sequential so you could, theoretically, order on them.